# How to select all available options in Wicket Palete?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wicket

I have a wicket palette in my HTML page and I need to select all the available options by default when parent options are selected. In below image, if I select an option `A`, the available options in wicket palette are shown as `A0,A1,A2,A3,A4`. 
Is there any way to select all these available options by default when option `A` is selected from the Drop down ? (All available options should move under selected by default) Users should be able to change their choices as needed.
[image]

Comment: In your DropDownChoice onUpdate() method, call setObject() on the palette to set the list of selected items.
Don't forget to add the palette to the AjaxRequestTarget

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code fragment to demonstrate a way of doing what you want

```
private Palette palette;
private DropDownChoice<String> select;

...

select.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

        palette.setObject(// your list of selected items // );

        target.add(palette);
    }
```